# Unable to connect to Postgresql database server remotely over LAN

Tags: postgresql, remote

Below is a screenshot of netstat command output from my database server.

[image]

I think it clearly shows that it will accept the connections from LAN over 5432.

But the below command is not working over LAN from my PC

[image]

I am using a Router on my LAN CISCO RV320 . Could you please point me the root-cause of this issue ?

Comment: _I think it clearly shows that it will accept the connections from LAN over 5432_: well, it shows the opposite. If you edit `postgresql.conf`, change `listen_addresses` to `*` to listen on all interfaces, relaunch postgres and retry the test you should see the difference in the "Local Address" column.

Comment: thanks for your inputs . i am able to connect now. I had changed the localhost to * but ignored the # at the beginning of the line ( in postgresql.conf file). I wasted 2 days for this . Thanks Daniel for your time.